# reviewing edits vs. editing

Tags: discussion, reviewing

As I understand it, when I edit an article, my edits go live immediately.

When I review somebody else's edit and approve it, it still needs more reviewers to approve the same change.

Is there a rationale behind this discrepancy?

Comment: The rationale might be that even if users have the edit privilege, they may not know what qualifies as a proper edit. Hence, the discrepancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once upon a time, the ability to edit someone else's post was restricted to users with a reputation of 2,000 or higher<sup>*</sup> (i.e. users who (hopefully) have the *experience* to use that feature appropriately).

We wanted to unlock the ability for more users to help with editing, so we created the /review system. *Any* user can "suggest" and edit for a post, but it must be 'reviewed' by at least two users with sufficient reputation to perform that function. This is way more engaging than the comments stating *“please sir, edit this for me.”* You need *two* people to do a review, because the review system is more prone to mistakes when the the reviewer isn't really accountable for the content itself.

That's where the discrepancy comes from.

<sup><sup>*</sup>*The reputation requirments to 'edit' change as the site passes from private to public beta and to graduation.*</sup>